# How can a werewolf fly?

Tags: magic, chronicles-of-darkness-1e, flight, werewolf-the-forsaken

How can I make my werewolf fly?
I feel like flying is within scope for things I expect a werewolf to be able to do, given enough XP.

I had thought that Mother Luna's second dot gift "anybeast" could do it, but on closer reading that just lets you apply a "custom skin" onto your wolf forms -- it doesn't change your capacity.

I am looking for a method for my werewolf to fly.

- Ideally method should not require any gifts/abilities that are restricted Auspice (since that can't be changed)
- it also should not (ideally) require any gifts/abilities that a restricted to Tribe or Lodge (but this is less important than the above)
- It could require some ability granted by Totem

A few ways other supernaturals can fly -- I am sure their are more, but these are just examples:

- Mages can fly via Forces (to levitate), or Life (to grow wings)
- Changelings can fly via Fang and Talon to turn into a bird.
- Vampires similarly via turning into a bat
- Sineaters can fly by going into a trance to activate marionette then their marionette can pick up their body and fly around carrying it.

Comment: Just for clarity, I assume you want this potential Werewolf to be capable of landing more than once, yes? :)

Comment: LOL That was my first thought as well, which led to wanting to type "Piss off a vampire with Potence" as an answer.

Comment: Is starting with Resources dots and buying an airplane considered cheating?

Comment: Have you seen any catapults lately?

Comment: James bond style jetpacks?

Comment: Potence is the answer to all questions. All.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Forsaken expert, but from what I can tell you're limited to the use of Fetishes:

- The Spirit Wings Fetish (one dot, WtF Core) lets you fall slowly or float horizontally.
- The Shadow Wings Fetish (three dots, WtF Core) lets you fly for hours, but only in the Shadow.
- The Condor Idol Fetish (two dots, Lodges: The Splintered) lets you fly in the Shadow at a lower dot cost, but it's Lodge-restricted.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to make a Fetish.

Since flying is relatively powerful, it'd probably be a 4-dot (for restricted altitude or about 20~30 minutes per day) or a 5-dot (unlimited use) Fetish.
Using the Fetish Rite (WtF:Core p162) with any large bird spirit, like a condor or an eagle would work.